# Does leaflet forgot to protect their access_token for mapbox?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I copied this example from Leaflet:

https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html

I'm able to deploy it without any restrictions. In fact I can use the mapbox access_token for any project in production. I must have missed something. I wonder if access is otherwise restricted for this access_token. For example by the number of calls per day from a certain domain? How is the misuse of this access_token prevented?

Answer (score 3):

Its hard to say what the restrictions are on leaflet's own mapbox token, though they may rotate tokens on a periodic basis, or it may have a max number of requests.  When you say "deploy", do you mean on localhost?  They may have any localhost addresses whitelisted, with the expectation that anyone using that token for dev purposes on their own machine is probably not making a ton of requests.

As far as your question "How is the misuse of this access_token prevented", when you create a token with your mapbox account, you can go to its settings (mapbox.com -> Account -> API Token -> click on your access token), and you'll see a screen like this:

[image]

Here is where you can determine what the token can be used for and any restrictions on what urls can access the token - pretty standard for a lot of api tokens.  The most important is the URLs section, where you can determine what domain origins can use your token.  So if you host a site at `mysite.com`, then you can add that domain to your urls, and that token will only work if the request that uses it has your domain in its origin header.

Mapbox also has a pretty great stats page for what your token is being used for. Lots more info [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/getting-started/access-tokens/).